# Set Date as keyField in list Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have used list to get data from the model and it works well

This example is from Cakephp docs

```
$query = $articles->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'slug',
    'valueField' => 'title'
]);
$data = $query->toArray();
```

I have a table name holidays

> id[int] | date[date] | name[varchar(200)] | created[datetime]

So want a list which has date as the key and holiday as value
Somthing like this

```
[
    '2016-01-01'=>'New Year',
    '2016-01-26'=>'Republic Day',
]
```

So i created model by cake bake and used this code to achive it

```
$holidays = TableRegistry::get('Holidays');
$holidays = $holidays->find('list',[
    'keyField' => 'date',
    'valueField'=>'name',
])->toArray();
```

But its giving me error

> Illegal offset type 
>   InvalidArgumentException

When i change the keyField from date with name it works great.

Here is the logs

> 2016-04-29 04:26:41 Error: [InvalidArgumentException] Illegal offset
>   type Request URL: /sfworxerp/api/attendances/getMonthAttendanceData
>   Stack Trace:
>   F:\public_html\sfworxerp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Collection\Iterator\MapReduce.php(160):
>   Cake\Collection\Iterator\MapReduce::emit()
>   F:\public_html\sfworxerp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Collection\CollectionTrait.php(386):
>   Cake\Collection\Iterator\MapReduce->emit('New Year',
>   Object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate))
>   F:\public_html\sfworxerp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Collection\Iterator\MapReduce.php(177):
>   Cake\ORM\ResultSet->Cake\Collection{closure}(Object(App\Model\Entity\Holiday),
>   0, Object(Cake\Collection\Iterator\MapReduce))
>   F:\public_html\sfworxerp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Collection\Iterator\MapReduce.php(132):
>   Cake\Collection\Iterator\MapReduce->_execute() [internal function]:
>   Cake\Collection\Iterator\MapReduce->getIterator()
>   F:\public_html\sfworxerp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Collection\Collection.php(50):
>   IteratorIterator->__construct(Object(Cake\Collection\Iterator\MapReduce))
>   F:\public_html\sfworxerp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Collection\CollectionTrait.php(405):
>   Cake\Collection\Collection->__construct(Object(Cake\Collection\Iterator\MapReduce))
>   F:\public_html\sfworxerp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Table.php(1062):
>   Cake\ORM\ResultSet->combine('date', 'name', NULL)
>   F:\public_html\sfworxerp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Datasource\QueryTrait.php(490):
>   Cake\ORM\Table->Cake\ORM{closure}(Object(Cake\ORM\ResultSet))
>   F:\public_html\sfworxerp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Query.php(1141):
>   Cake\ORM\Query->_applyDecorators(Object(Cake\ORM\ResultSet))
>   F:\public_html\sfworxerp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Datasource\QueryTrait.php(272):
>   Cake\ORM\Query->_decorateResults(Object(Cake\ORM\ResultSet))
>   F:\public_html\sfworxerp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Query.php(871):
>   Cake\ORM\Query->_all()
>   F:\public_html\sfworxerp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Datasource\QueryTrait.php(288):
>   Cake\ORM\Query->all()
>   F:\public_html\sfworxerp\src\Controller\Api\AttendancesController.php(133):
>   Cake\ORM\Query->toArray() [internal function]:
>   App\Controller\Api\AttendancesController->getMonthAttendanceData()
>   F:\public_html\sfworxerp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Controller\Controller.php(429):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>   F:\public_html\sfworxerp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Dispatcher.php(114):
>   Cake\Controller\Controller->invokeAction()
>   F:\public_html\sfworxerp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Dispatcher.php(87): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\Api\AttendancesController))
>   F:\public_html\sfworxerp\webroot\index.php(37):
>   Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request),
>   Object(Cake\Network\Response)) {main}

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Can you verify that by simply removing the key/value array makes it error-free?  `$holidays = $holidays->find('list')->toArray();`

Comment: When i make it 
`$holidays = TableRegistry::get('Holidays');
$holidays = $holidays->find('list',[
    'keyField' => 'id',
    'valueField'=>'name',
])->toArray();` When i change the keyField from date to name it works great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The Problem:**

The problem is, for 'date' fields, CakePHP 3 returns an object, not a string:

```
'date' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {
    'time' => '1997-01-03T00:00:00+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false
},
```

Trying to use that as the key doesn't work, and throws the error you're seeing.

**How to handle:**

Per [this area in the CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs), to accommodate this, you can:

> use closures to access entity mutator methods in your list finds.

**TLDR Do this:**

```
$query = $articles->find('list', [
    'keyField' => function ($e) {
         return $e->date->format('Y-m-d');
     },
    'valueField' => 'title'
]);
```

**Explanation for how it works:**

Basically, it puts the value of each entity (in your case each article) into the variable `$e`, and allows you to use/modify it's data, and return the string you want to use as the key (or value) field.  In the case above, it's getting the `date` object, and formatting it into a string before returning it to be used as the key.

Comment: It works great. I know why the error is coming but cant get the solution to resolve that error. Saved my day :)

Comment: Next time, if you know why the error, please include that in your question to make it easier on the people trying to help! :)

Comment: Yes i mentioned that in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a similar example and I got your same error.

Looking at the error stack seems it's related to the fact that cake returns a Time object and not a string.

I found a workaround: you can created a virtual field in your entity

**Holyday Entity**

```
protected function _getFormattedDate()
{
    if(isset($this->date))
        return $this->date->format('Y-m-d');
    return null;
}
```

so you can do

```
$holidays = $holidays->find('list',[
    'keyField' => 'formatted_date',
    'valueField'=>'name',
])->toArray();
```

you can also use Dave's suggestion to create a custom finder.

**HolidaysTable**

```
public function findDate(Query $query, array $options)
{

    $options['keyField'] = function ($e) {
        if(isset($e->date))
            return $e->date->format('Y-m-d');
        return null;
    };
    $options['valueField'] = 'name';

    return  $this->findList($query, $options);
}
```

I just added a control on whether date field is set otherwise you could get an error.

**controller**

```
$holidays->find('date')->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it work great. But i will accept Dave answer because that seams the right way to do. Thanks again :)

Comment: I would have accepted dave's answer too ;-). Anyway I improved my answer to add a solution you can easily reuse